# vim: Change default paste register

Tags: vim

When I yank or delete text in vim, and run `:reg`, I see that it's going in to register `"`. But when I paste, I see "E353: Nothing in register: *"

What I get out of this is that vim is yanking to `"` but pasting from `*`.

> `:set clipboard?`
>   \ `clipboard=`
>   `:echo version`
>   \ `704`

Is it possible to change the register that vim attempts to yank from? Or am I asking the wrong question?

EDIT:

To yank, I use `yy` (or `dd` or `ci'` etc).

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Are you having trouble pasting? What are you hoping to achieve? What command are you using to yank?

Comment: `set clipboard=unnamed` will make `*` the default register. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: What command did you use to "paste"? It looks like you *don't* have "unnamed" in your clipboard, so normally Vim should NOT be trying to access the '*' register.

Comment: Please see the edit; I yank with yy but this applies to any command that would put the text in the paste buffer.

Comment: I had this problem - it is quite confusing and frustrating. Having the clipboard set to 'unnamedplus' was the culprit for me. Try a different setting: ':set clipboard=autoselect' seems to produce good results.

Comment: This is bizarre. I had it working in Mac Homebrew `vim` with `set clipboard=unnamed`. It's always worked until this morning suddenly it didn't. I use `vim` inside `tmux` inside an `ssh` session from a Linux host (to avoid MacOs). Now when I `ddp` I get that same error "nothing in register *". But `set clipboard?` says `unnamed`. So as of today I'm using `set clipboard=autoselect` but why did that have to change without warning? I just installed Tmux resurrect but this is happening outside of Tmux in the raw terminal too.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this issue may be involved: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/203

Answer (score 27):

You can't change the default register: it will always be the unnamed register, `"`.

What you can do, though, is synchronize the unnamed register with the clipboard register:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed
```

See `:help 'clipboard'`.

For reference…

Vim's documentation generally advises to add your custom values to the default ones rather than overriding them. You can do that with `+=` to append or `^=` to prepend. On Windows or Mac OS X, the default value of `clipboard` is empty so `set clipboard=unnamed` could be enough but the default value on Linux doesn't accept anything after its last entry so `unnamed` must be prepended. `set clipboard^=unnamed` is a safer, cross-platform, choice:

```
:set clipboard^=unnamed
:set clipboard?

Linux:    unnamed,autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux
Mac OS X: unnamed
Windows:  unnamed
```

Comment: On my Fedora 24 machine with vim-X11.x86_64 worked only by setting clipboard to the + register: `set clipboard=unnamedplus`. The safer(^=) version did not work.

Comment: 6 years later, and the comment above still applies to Ubuntu 21.10. Only got it working by doing `set clipboard=unnamedplus`.