# Is it possible to change the default paste register in Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, x11

I am trying to make it so that all normal yank and put commands will use the register `+` in addition to, or instead of the unnamed register.

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946289/vim-change-default-paste-register) but the solution presented there does not work on Linux. I have also looked at `:help x11-selection` and `:help quoteplus`, but neither contains the answer.

**How can I make all `y` commands to behave as if they are prepended by `"+`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `set clipboard^=unnamedplus` for the `+` version of unnamed.

Take a look at `:help clipboard-unnamedplus`

Comment: @merlin2011 Don't remember. Its something I stumbled across a long time ago. (But you could also scroll down in `:h 'clipboard'`)